# How to access the data of the edges of the vertex in graph?

Tags: c++, graph

I am trying to figure out how I could access the values of the edges of the vertex so that I can print the graph.

**This is my implementation of addEdge:**

```
void clsGraph::add_edge(clsVertex* source, clsVertex* destination, int id, double weght)
{
    clsEdge *a = new clsEdge;
    a->ID = id;
    a->weight = weght;
    a->destination_vertex = destination;
    source->edges.push_back(a);
}
```

**This is my vertex class:**

```
#ifndef CLSVERTEX_HPP
#define CLSVERTEX_HPP

#include <vector>
#include "clsEdge.hpp"

using namespace std; //namespace Rajkarnikar 
{   
    class clsVertex
    {   
        public:
        int ID; //integer used to uniquely ID a vertex      
        vector<clsEdge*> edges; //a vector of pointers to a vertex’s edges
    }; //
}
#endif
```

and I have this command to add my vertex:

```
void clsGraph::add_vertex(clsVertex* vertex)
{
    verticies.push_back(vertex);
}
```

What I am trying to do is access the vertices and then check if it has any edges or not and output those edges as well.

can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Simply use for_each() & print the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion :)
This was the solution I used...

```
 cout << ID << " " << graphType << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < verticies.size(); i++){
            cout << verticies[i]->ID << "->";
            for (int j = 0; j < verticies[i]->edges.size(); j++){
                cout << verticies[i]->edges[j]->ID << endl;
            }
```